# How to install rails 3.0 on Redhat 4.0 with mysql2 support?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redhat

When trying to install rails 3.0 on a redhat 4.0 server, the 'bundle install' fails during the installation of mysql2.

Is it possible to solve this?

'bundle install' command returns the following output:

```
~/rails/trial# bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.0) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.4.1) 
Using activemodel (3.0.0) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.6) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.23) 
Using actionpack (3.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.8) 
Using mail (2.2.6.1) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.0) 
Using arel (1.0.1) 
Using activerecord (3.0.0) 
Using activeresource (3.0.0) 
Using bundler (1.0.3) 
Installing mysql2 (0.2.4) with native extensions /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -I/usr/include/mysql -g -pipe -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wall -funroll-loops  -o client.o -c client.c
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:29,
                 from client.c:1:
./client.h:41:7: warning: no newline at end of file
client.c: In function `set_reconnect':
client.c:434: error: `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT' undeclared (first use in this function)
client.c:434: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
client.c:434: error: for each function it appears in.)
client.c: In function `set_connect_timeout':
client.c:451: warning: passing arg 3 of `mysql_options' from incompatible pointer type
make: *** [client.o] Error 1
```

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.4 for inspection.

```
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `block in build_extensions'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:100:in `install'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:221:in `install'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
 from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
 from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please add your paste in a code block (indent 4 spaces), that'll make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the appropriate development libraries installed? E.g. `libmysqlclient-16-dev` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I believe it is too old?

```
~/rails/trial# rpm -qa|grep mysql
mysqlclient10-devel
mysqlclient10
mysql-devel
mysql-server
mysql
```

However everything seems up to date as far as RHEL4 gets (and upgrading isn't really an option)

```
~/rails/trial# up2date --showall|grep mysql
mysql-4.1.22-2.el4_8.3.x86_64
mysql-bench-4.1.22-2.el4_8.3.x86_64
mysql-devel-4.1.22-2.el4_8.3.x86_64
mysql-server-4.1.22-2.el4_8.3.x86_64
mysqlclient10-3.23.58-4.RHEL4.1.x86_64
mysqlclient10-devel-3.23.58-4.RHEL4.1.x86_64

~/rails/trial# /usr/bin/mysql_config
Usage: /usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
    --cflags         [-I/usr/include/mysql -g -pipe -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing]
    --include        [-I/usr/include/mysql]
    --libs           [-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto]
    --libs_r         [-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lpthread -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lpthread -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto]
    --socket         [/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock]
    --port           [3306]
    --version        [4.1.22]
    --libmysqld-libs [-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqld -lz -lpthread -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lpthread -lrt]
```